# Inserting message parameters into MySQL database using Python

Tags: python, mysql

Here's some code that I am using to try and insert data into a MySQL database.

break_down(s) is a function that I am using to parse message parameters. These parameters are getting parsed as required.

However, when I try to insert these values they aren't getting saved in the MySQL database even though I am using commit. Why is this?

```
def break_down(s):
    c=s.count('<')
    if c==9:
            res = re.findall('< (.*?) >', s)
            for index in res:
                print index,item
    elif c==7 or c==3:
            temp=parsing(s)
            pprint(list(temp))
    else:
        flag=0
        c=s.count(':')
        if c==8:
            res=s.split(' : ')
            res=[item.strip() for item in s.split(':')]
            for index, item in enumerate(res):
                print index, item
            results = [float(x) for x in s.split(' ') if x.count('.') == 1]
            pprint(results)
            dbinsert(res[0],res[1],res[2],res[3],results[0],results[1],results[2],results[3],flag)
        if c==7:
            flag=1
            res=s.split(' : ')
            res=[item.strip() for item in s.split(':')]
            for index, item in enumerate(res):
                print index, item
            results = [float(x) for x in s.split(' ') if x.count('.') == 1]
            pprint(results)
            dbinsert(res[0],res[1],res[2],res[3],results[0],results[1],results[2],results[3],flag)


def parsing(s):
        for t in s.split('<'):
            for u in t.strip().split('>',1):
                if u.strip(): yield u.strip()


def dbinsert(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,flag):
 import MySQLdb
 db = MySQLdb.Connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=3306, user="root", passwd="root", db="ups")
 print "In dbinsert"
 cursor = db.cursor()
 try:
  if flag==0:
   sql = """INSERT INTO data(F1,
          F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8)
          VALUES (a.value,b.value,c.value,d.value,e.value,f.value,g.value,h.value)"""
   cursor.execute(sql)
   db.commit()
  elif flag==1:
   sql = """INSERT INTO data(F1,
          F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8)
          VALUES (a,b,c,,e,f,g,h)"""
   cursor.execute(sql)
   db.commit()
 except:
  db.rollback()
  db.close()
```

Comment: What is `a` in `VALUES (a.value,b.value,c.value,d.value,e.value,f.value,g.value,h.value)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass any parameters in your query, the query you execute contains the literals `a.value, b.value, ...` or `a, b, ...`, which the database of course doesn't know anything to do with.

To make it work you need something in the line of:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO data(F1, F2, F3, ...) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, ...)"""
cursor.execute(sql, (a, b, c, ...))
```

Thiss will correctly escape the values and bind them to the query before executing it.